# Проблема с запуском после добавления SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

После добавления этих строк приложение перестало запускаться и телефон выдаёт что там угроза

Сохранение

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("best_score", score);
        editor.commit();
```

Загрузка

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
if (sharedPreferences.contains("best_score")) {
            // we have a high score saved, load it...
            int bestscore = sharedPreferences.getInt("best_score", -1);
            scores.setText("Лучший : " + bestscore);
            // here you'd like to do something with the value, for example display it.
        } else {
            scores.setText("Лучший : 0");
            // there is no high score value - you should probably hide the "best score" TextView
        }
```

UPD: проверял-проверял и заметил, что как только добавляю строчку `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();` тут же приложение перестаёт запускаться

Comment: какая именно "угроза"?

Comment: @pavlofff может содержать вирусы

Comment: у меня такое было когда я создал приложение с иконкой и названием из ВКонтакте и с пекейжем com.vkontakte.hack. может у вас что-то такое же?

Comment: @Flippy но раньше этого не было.. и иконки и package я не менял

Comment: @Flippy только что специально закомментировал все строки связанные с SharedPreferences и всё заработало

Comment: попробуй поменять `getPreferences` на `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`

Comment: @Flippy можно поподробнее? И да, заметил что до того как добавляю загрузку во время запуска приложения всё работает, но после ни в какую.. как можно ещё попробовать запустить?

Comment: К сожалению, пас, попробуйте использовать стандартный код получения SharedPreferences. Имхо, getPreferences виноват, но я этот метод вообще не знаю

Comment: @Flippy ладно, спасибо. Попробую разобраться

Comment: @Flippy попробовал, и тоже самое..

Comment: а кто вам выдает предупреждение о угрозе, какой то антивирус на устройстве? В коде нет ничего, что могло бы быть вирусом и проблема на в вашем коде, а в том, кто его обнаружил

Comment: @pavlofff антивирус самого телефона

Answer (score 0):

Для получения **SharedPreferences** не нужно запускать **Editor**. И проверку `.contains()` делать тоже не нужно, это сильно замедляет время загрузки, особенно если код находится в `onCreate()`.

Делайте примерно как-то так:

```
mSharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int bestscore = mSharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.best_score), 0);
scores.setText("Лучший : " + bestscore);
```

Если `best_score` отсутствует, то будет использовано значение по умолчанию `0`.